# Do I need a different product type for WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

We are running a WooCommerce WP website that sells fabrics for upholstery. We will soon be looking to sell cushions, blankets etc.

What would be the best way to manage these different products?
Or can they be listed with the fabrics but separated with a category.

Comment: Categories are used to group similar products. Amazon can sell both Ipods and Couches but will separate them in different categories Electronics and Furniture respectively. So you're right, categories would be the right approach in this scenario.

Comment: Can you provide the website link, so that we can suggest you the best way to manage your products?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need different product type for WooCommerce.
WooCommerce products are already categorized under [four types](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/managing-products/).
The best to organize your WooCommerce site data is using [categories, tags and attributes](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/managing-product-taxonomies/). As you are going to add some new products in your business, this is the right time to plan.

*Here we recommend you to make different categories for cushions, blankets etc,* so that buyer can easily browse through your website.